# Difference between Task Manager and Process Explorer regarding CPU utilization

Tags: performance, cpu-usage

When I open Task Manager and Process Explorer I can see they present different CPU utilization values. Moreover, *'Processes'* and *'Details'* tabs in the **same** Task Manager indicate different CPU utilization values. I want to understand why, so I tried doing some research.

I have a guess that the difference is because some performance monitors include the CPU speed in their calculations while others don't. To test that theory I created a simple infinite loop in python which does not use IO: `while True: pass`. This should exhaust the core it is running in, as it does not use IO at all so there is no spare time for the core to idle.

I ran the loop to see the results:

- **Process Explorer:** python.exe 8.34%
- **Task Manager's Details tab:** python.exe 8%
- **Resource Monitor:** Maximum frequency 180%
- **Task Manager's Process tab:** python.exe 16.8%
- **Process Explorer CPU usage:** 10.28%
- **Resource Monitor:** CPU usage 19%
- **Task Manager's Performance tab:** CPU utilization 19%

Now let's do some math and explain these values. I am using 12 logical processors with base speed of 2.21GHz, so the results are:

- **Process Explorer:** python.exe 8.34%

  - My python program should exhaust a single core. My system has 12 logical cores so 100/12 is approximately 8.34.
- **Task Manager's Details tab:** python.exe 8%

  - Same as previous calculation, but task manager rounds the result to 8%.
- **Resource Monitor:** Maximum frequency 180%

  - 180% of the base speed is approximately 3.98GHz, which was my CPU speed during the test.
- **Task Manager's Process tab:** python.exe 16.6%

  - 180% of 8.34 is 15, which is not exactly 16.6 but pretty close...
- **Process Explorer CPU usage:** 10.28%

  - It seems like the 'real' CPU usage without any scale.
- **Resource Monitor:** CPU usage 19%

  - 180% of 10.28 is 18.5 which is pretty close
- **Task Manager's Performance tab:** CPU utilization 19%

  - Same as in Task Manager Performance tab

It all adds up to be pretty simple: Process Explorer shows the usage of the cpu without any scale, Task Manager and Resource Monitor show it with a scale of the current CPU speed (except for the *Details* tab for some reason). It also seems like Task Manager cannot show values over 100%, but Resource Monitor can.

I tried it one more time, now with several loops on several cores, so the difference would be more significant:

- **Resource Monitor:** Maximum frequency 156%

  - 156% of the base speed is approximately 3.44GHz, which was my CPU speed during the test.
- **Process Explorer CPU usage:** 69.57%

  - It seems like the 'real' CPU usage without any scale.
- **Resource Monitor:** CPU usage 109%

  - 156% of 69.57 is 108.52 which can be rounded to 109.
- **Task Manager's Performance tab:** CPU utilization 100%

  - Same as Resource Monitor, but is capped to 100%

**So my question is:**
Am I correct? I tried to find any evidence around the web but it seems like no one has done the same math. In fact some people gave contradicting explanations to this difference... Am I missing something?

---

I've found similar questions in this site, but their answers seem incorrect or irrelevant to my question:

- Some of them explained that there might be processes from other users. It is not relevant here as I see processes from all users.
- Some other answers explained that Process Explorer and Task Manager have different polling algorithms. this is fine but it does not explain the different values of *Processes* and *Details* tabs of the same Task Manager.
- Other answers mentioned that there is no connection between CPU usage and CPU speed. As I understand this is wrong because clearly there is a connection (as I showed above), and this connection actually explains the difference. Am I missing something?

The questions I have read:

- [CPU Utilization in Task Manager](https://superuser.com/questions/1094246/cpu-utilization-in-task-manager)
- [Task manager: CPU Utilization and speed?](https://superuser.com/questions/629777/task-manager-cpu-utilization-and-speed)
- [How CPU speed is managed vs CPU utilization?](https://superuser.com/questions/1352409/how-cpu-speed-is-managed-vs-cpu-utilization)
- [What is CPU utilization and how is it calculated, how does OS scheduling work?](https://superuser.com/questions/952004/what-is-cpu-utilization-and-how-is-it-calculated-how-does-os-scheduling-work)
- [What is the most accurate way of measuring cpu utilization of processes in Windows based systems](https://serverfault.com/questions/903585/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-of-measuring-cpu-utilization-of-processes-in-windo)

Comment: Did you see this page>>>>https://medium.com/@ppatali/sysinternals-tools-process-explorer-and-process-monitor-6252b919e5fb

Comment: @Moab I have read it now, bit it only describes how to use Process Explorer (which I already used in my question) and Process Monitor (which is not relevant to my question)

Comment: Same issue here. My PC is in near idle state, PE shows < 1%, TM shows around 10% - 20%. I was trying to track what causes my fans to spin and TM seems to better tool for that, whet TM shows > 15%, my fans are audibly up while PE keeps pretending that nothing is happening.